# Android Restlet HTTPS

Tags: android, https, restlet

When trying to get some data on my android client from my webservice (running on app-engine) with this code

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("https://myapp.appspot.com/restlet/service/");
IServiceResource res = cr.wrap(IServiceResource.class);
m_Services = res.getServices();
```

I get this error:

```
05-20 08:30:15.406: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31767): Caused by: Communication Error (1001) - Could not change the mode after the initial handshake has begun.
```

i have the org.restlet.ext.ssl.jar for the https-support and i am using this line to add the client

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().add(new HttpsClientHelper(null));
```

this is the closest i have come to getting https:// calls to work since i moved up to restlet 2.1m4 (moved because i was in need of entityBuffering..)

Any ideas?
Any other information i need to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working.
Changed HttpClient to org.restlet.ext.net.

On Android, you are told to do this to change the client

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().add(new HttpClientHelper(null));
```

However nothing changes by doing so, instead, i had success with

```
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().clear();
Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().add(new HttpClientHelper(null));
```

This solves the issu(be sure to have org.restlet.ext.ssl in your build path aswell).
This also solves other issues such as the "Internal Connector Error (1002) - The calling thread timed out while waiting for a response to unblock it."

Answer (score 0):

I had worked with web service using ksoap2, u can try using ksoap2 by downloading the jar and including in ur project.

Comment: You mean using ksoap2 as an restlet extension?

Comment: no its another way to use web service, you can google and find out information abt ksoap2

Comment: Interesting, however my question is about restlet.