# Restlet Android doesn't connect to oData service

Tags: android, odata, restlet

I just can't get Restlet on Android to work. I have the same jars, same generated classes etc. that I use in plain Java (it works there). Problem seems to be with the HttpClientHelper.

I also read this: http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/275-restlet/266-restlet.html.

Here's my code:

```
import netflix.catalog.v2.Genre;
import org.restlet.engine.Engine;
import org.restlet.ext.net.HttpClientHelper;
import org.restlet.ext.odata.Query;

        Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().clear();
        Engine.getInstance().getRegisteredClients().add(new HttpClientHelper(null)); 

        SystemDataObjectsService service = new SystemDataObjectsService();  

        Query<Genre> query = service.createGenreQuery("/Genres");


        for (Genre g : query) {
            Log.d(TAG, g.getName());
        }
```

Here's the trace:

```
11-16 13:02:31.915: I/org.restlet(1344): Starting the HTTP client
11-16 13:02:31.924: I/org.restlet(1344): A recoverable error was detected (1001), attempting again in 2000 ms.
11-16 13:02:33.935: I/org.restlet(1344): A recoverable error was detected (1001), attempting again in 2000 ms.
11-16 13:02:35.955: E/org.restlet(1344): Can't get the metadata for http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/ (response's status: Communication Error (1001) - The connector failed to complete the communication with the server)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344): Can't parse the content of http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Genres
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344): java.lang.Exception: Can't execute the query without the service's metadata.
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344):    at org.restlet.ext.odata.Query.execute(Query.java:350)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344):    at org.restlet.ext.odata.Query.iterator(Query.java:645)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344):    at net.ascorbin.locaspo.MainActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:74)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344):    at net.ascorbin.locaspo.MainActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/org.restlet(1344):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-16 13:02:35.965: W/dalvikvm(1344): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
```

I also tried to import org.restlet.ext.httpclient.HttpClientHelper (and any other HttpClientHelper that Eclipse suggests) which lead to a slightly different trace:

```
11-16 13:06:27.775: I/org.restlet(1446): Get the metadata for http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/ at http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/$metadata
11-16 13:06:27.815: I/org.restlet(1446): Starting the HTTP client
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446): An error occurred during the communication with the remote HTTP server.
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "odata.netflix.com": No address associated with hostname
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:400)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:335)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.engine.http.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:120)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.engine.http.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:113)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:180)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:944)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:912)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:867)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:892)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.handle(ClientResource.java:801)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.resource.ClientResource.get(ClientResource.java:544)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.ext.odata.Service.getMetadata(Service.java:483)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.ext.odata.Query.<init>(Query.java:232)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at org.restlet.ext.odata.Service.createQuery(Service.java:277)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at net.ascorbin.locaspo.SystemDataObjectsService.createGenreQuery(SystemDataObjectsService.java:87)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at net.ascorbin.locaspo.MainActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:71)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at net.ascorbin.locaspo.MainActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-16 13:06:27.836: W/org.restlet(1446):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-16 13:06:27.836: I/org.restlet(1446): A recoverable error was detected (1001), attempting again in 2000 ms.
```

I don't know what else to do, if someone has a running Restlet/ oData android project, perhaps he/ she can give me a hint?

Comment: I have same issues. Found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068303/android-restlet-https. Solution provided there didn't resolved my problems but maybe will help you...

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible code?

Comment: This looks like a DNS/IP connectivity issue. To be sure you could try to manually invoke Netflix OData service using the low level java.net.HttpURLConnection class